# node.js cron job not starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I use express.js and 'cron' module for auto db updating, so I dont know where should I add my cron init code, so I added it  to my app.js file, but after server started and 3 minutes awaiting I see now messages at console.

```
var cronJob=require('cron').CronJob;
new cronJob('* */3 * * * *', function(){ // i think that means every 3 minutes 
    console.log('Every 3 minutes');
    catalogUpdater.catalogUpdater(function(err, result){
        if(err) {
            log.err("router " + err);

        }else {
            log.warn(result);
            descriptionDownloader.descriptionDownloader(function(err, result){
                if(err) log.err(err);


            });
        }
    });
});
```

So where I need to put my cron start job?

Comment: It looks like you want to update the page on the client side in the browser every three minutes?

Comment: no, I just want to set cron interval for database update function, so run catalogUpdater.catalogUpdater(..) function every 3 minutes

Comment: Then why did you call functions page rendering `res.render`?

Comment: Sorry, didnt remove code from controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start cron job you need call `job.start()` or pass true as fourth argument of job constructor:

`constructor(cronTime, onTick, onComplete, start, timezone, context)`

P.S. If you use the classic frame Express application, you should create a task to put in a separate file and to connect it to the main file bin / www

Comment: Thx, so I create file updareCron.js , so I can use it by adding to 'www' require('updateCron'); ?

Comment: Yes, as an option. Also, if more than one task, it is possible to create a separate folder in the project code-named `cron`, break tasks into separate files, and connect the entire folder.